# How to make input not required?

Tags: angular

I use this validation rule:

```
 this.addVisitorForm = this.fb.group({company: [null, []]});
```

As you can see there is not validation for field `company`. But Angular says it is invalid, how to do this field not necessary?

**HTML code is:**

```
<input maxlength="25" [ngClass]="{ 'has-error': addVisitorForm.get('company').invalid }"formControlName="company" type="text" class="form-control form-control-lg" required>
```

Comment: Can you paste the HTML code? What do you mean 'Angular says it is invalid'? Do you see any error message? If yes, what is this error message?

Comment: Sure, I have added

Comment: Invalid means this is true: `addVisitorForm.get('company').invalid`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have mixed up the `HTML 5` validations and the `reactive form` validations. Remove the `required` attribute from the `<input>` tag

```
<input maxlength="25" [ngClass]="{ 'has-error': addVisitorForm.get('company').invalid }"formControlName="company" type="text" class="form-control form-control-lg">
```